# How can I put two buttons into a box and separate by line?

Tags: swift, button, layout

I am designing a screen and what I want to achieve is put two buttons and labels into a box and separate them by a line, as shown below on the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use a stack view and stack the two buttons plus a “thin” view which can be the line

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons are in UItoolbar you can use:
**Fixed space bar button item**

You can add them inside objects or simply use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and search for it
or just add an image to separate them.